# App rejection from appstore due to bluetooth error

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My app got rejected in app store saying some nsbluetoothdescription after that i changed bluetooth settings in info.plist(bluetooth peripheral usage-would like to access bluetooth for communication with printer) file still it is rejected by app store what to do now?anyone can pls help.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is a bit sparse but it looks like you also need the new:

"Privacy - Bluetooth Always Usage Description"

key: NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription

Then add a description to it to convince the user to allow your app to use bluetooth.

Seems like loads of apps have been tracking our location through the Bluetooth beacons we come into range with, so Apple are now requiring permission from the user.

See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsbluetoothalwaysusagedescription

Comment: instead of this Privacy - Bluetooth Always Usage Description i placed NSBlutoothAlwaysUsageDescription and works fine.apple accepted my app-thank u

Comment: Yes, "Privacy - Bluetooth Always Usage Description" is the friendly documentation name. As you say, NSBlutoothAlwaysUsageDescription is the actual key. Great it worked, and thanks for reporting back, I think a few folks will be caught out by this change so this should help them too. I'll edit the answer to include the key name.